# Postgresql 10 There is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: postgresql, update, foreign-key, insert

I currently have a table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "PDPC".collection
(
    col_no bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"PDPC".collection_col_no_seq'::regclass),
    q1 character varying(10000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    q2 character varying(10000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    q3 character varying(10000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    q4 character varying(10000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dg_fkey bigint,
    CONSTRAINT collection_pkey PRIMARY KEY (col_no),
    CONSTRAINT collection_dg_fkey_fkey FOREIGN KEY (dg_fkey)
        REFERENCES "PDPC".datagroup (dg_no) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE "PDPC".collection
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I am trying to execute an UPSERT statement in PHP using postgresql, but i received

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P10]: Invalid column reference: 7 ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification in C:\Apache24\htdocs\consideration.php:77 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\consideration.php(77): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\consideration.php on line 77

My web page currently has a form that takes in a user input of answers to four questions, and these questions will go into `"PDPC".collection` table. I want to run INSERT or UPDATE according to the `dm_fkey`, which is the foreign key I have set for this table.

This is the UPSERT statement that I used.

```
INSERT INTO "PDPC".collection (q1, q2, q3, q4, dg_fkey)
      VALUES (:q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :dg_no)
      ON CONFLICT(dg_fkey) DO UPDATE 
      SET q1=:q1, q2=:q2, q3=:q3, q4=:q4
```

Comment: Conflicts happen due to unique or exclusion constraints, not from FOREIGN KEY constraints. Is `dg_fkey` supposed to be unique?

Answer (score 5):

> ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification in

This because `dg_fkey` is a column referenced in a `FOREIGN KEY` `CONSTRAINT` and **not** an index. In fact, if you want that to be faster, you may consider additionally adding an index. From the docs on [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

You probably want something like this,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX asdf ON pdpc.collection(dg_fkey);
```

Or add it the the ddl,

```
CREATE TABLE pdpc.collection
(
    dg_fkey bigint UNIQUE
```

Then your upsert will work.

---

**Also never use double-quotes on identifiers, that's a horrible practice in Pg**

Comment: This is NOT because it is **"not an index."**

Comment: Exactly as @ypercubeᵀᴹ sais it has nothing to do with an index. The error is that the ON CONFLICT condition must bu unique, i.e - being a PK or a set of columns that can uniquely identify a row

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error message. In my case, I thought a table had a `UNIQUE` constraint but it did not.

I had a query like this:

```
INSERT ... into <table>
ON CONFLICT ...
```

Thinking that `ON CONFLICT` would handle problems when the `UNIQUE` constraint was violated.

But there was no `UNIQUE` constraint on the table and therefore the `ON CONFLICT` made no sense.